# Error 'uiGrid' must have exactly one root element. ui-grid/ui-grid when UI-Grid is initiated

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

While trying to add ui-grid to an angular project, I came across this issue.

I’ve bootstrapped the angel;ar application with ui-grid dependency injected.

```
    var app = angular.module(‘myApp’,     
    ['ui.bootstrap',     
     'services',     
     'filters',         
     'directives',         
     'controllers',         
     'ui.grid'     
    ]);
```

The controller looks like this.

```
   angular.module('controllers').controller('UIGridCtrl',function      UIGridCtrl($scope) {  
  $scope.init = function(){         
      $scope.myData = [             
        {"firstName": "Cox",
          "lastName": "Carney",
          "company": "Enormo", 
          "employed": true             
         } ];     
       };
    });
```

The view is

```
    <div ng-controller="UIGridCtrl">
         <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{data: myData}" class="grid"></div>  
    </div>
```

since grunt was used, I’ve added the ui-grid dependencies in my index template as well.

```
<!-- include: "type": "css", "files": "javascripts/library/uiGrid/ui-grid-stable.css" -->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "javascripts/library/uiGrid/ui-grid-stable.js"  -->
```

When I try to access my view, I get this error.

**Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'uiGrid' must have exactly one root element. ui-grid/ui-grid.**

Apart fro that, there is a network call to this url.

http://localhost:PORT/ui-grid/ui-grid which is an invalid url. Not sure what is the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tried replicating this with no luck..take a look at this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Gfv6Q6tlTmcyNdeFx6eg?p=preview . The only issue i see is the $scope.init() is not invoked so your myData scope variable is never set.

Comment: any reason for the thrown error? I have my initial plunker, but that it the simple implementation.  http://plnkr.co/edit/iVkiPIM7UPBos0Ix7lrL?p=preview

Comment: can you share the index html generated after the grunt. I kinda doubt thats where the problem is.

Comment: in my index.html , I have the references to both ng-grid and ui-grid.  (Ng-grid being my legacy grid). The paths are correct. Can this be an issue with ng-grid and ui-grid clashing ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt According to this, the html comments can cause this issue. Take a look at the html and make sure there are no comments just after the ui-grid definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was related to an odd http interception. When ui-grid was added, it was triggering a get request to http://localhost:xxxx/ng-grid/ng-grid, which was breaking the grid and throwing the error. ('uiGrid' must have exactly one root element. ui-grid/ui-grid)
Added an intercepter rule to ignore that url format and then the grids started rendering fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using http interceptor, omit the urls with ui-grid which clears this error.

Below is my final working code

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myapp').config(myHttpProvider);
})();



function appHttpInterceptor($q, $injector) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
            // do something on success
             if ((config.url.indexOf('tpl.html') === -1) && 
             (config.url.indexOf('tabler-icons') === -1) && (config.url.indexOf('ui-grid/') === -1)) {
                config.url = window.APP.api + config.url;
            }
            return config;
        },

        // optional method
        'requestError': function(rejection) {
            // do something on error
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },

        // optional method
        'response': function(response) {
            // do something on success
            if (response.config.url.indexOf('ui-grid/') !== -1) {
                return response;
            }
            if (response.config.url.indexOf('tpl.html') !== -1) {
                return response;
            }
            if (response.config.url.indexOf('tpl.html') !== -1) {
                return response;
            }
            if (response.config.url.indexOf('tabler-icons') !== -1) {
                return response;
            }
            const data = response.data;
            
            if(data.message){
                const toastService = $injector.get('ToastService');
                toastService.success(data.message);
            }
            if (data.redirect) {
                window.location.href = data.redirect;
            }
            return data;
        },

        // optional method
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            // do something on error
            let data = rejection.data;
            let errors = [data.message];
            if (data.errors) {
                const errorValues = Object.values(data.errors);
                if (errorValues.length) {
                    errors = [];
                    _.forEach(errorValues, function(error) {
                        errors = errors.concat(error)
                    });
                }
            }
    const toastService = $injector.get('ToastService');
            toastService.error(errors[0]);
            return $q.reject(errors);
        }
    };
}

function myHttpProvider($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(appHttpInterceptor);
}

myHttpProvider.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
appHttpInterceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$injector'];
```

**config.url.indexOf('ui-grid/') !== -1** is the key.